# Failed to remove reactions: DiscordAPIError[60003]: Two factor is required for this operation

Tags: discord.js

This bit of code is failing in a bot I'm making:

```js
if (reaction.emoji.id === '1086474462834200687') { //If stop emoji
  if (user.id != '235113888973062155') { // If the user who added the stop emoji isnt Admin then remove it
    reaction.message.reactions.cache.get('1086474462834200687').remove()
      .catch(error => console.error('Failed to remove reactions:', error));
  }
}
```

And it is throwing the error:

> Failed to remove reactions: DiscordAPIError[60003]: Two factor is required for this operation

I am the owner of the bot and 2FA is enabled on my account. However, I am developing this for a friend of mine so the discord server that the bot is running on is not mine, he owns it.

This was not failing up until about a week ago and I am using the same account. Any suggestions to fix this would be welcome. If you need any further information please let me know.